# Selenium python- Is it possible to draw a circle around clicked GUI elements?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, canvas, drawing

I am new to selenium and I am wondering if I could draw a red circle around anything my selenium script clicks before taking a screenshot of the page (I already know how to do the screenshot). I think that I could utilize:

```
ele.location
```

and

```
ele.size
```

to draw a circle, but I just do not know how. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: You can create an arc around using canvas

Comment: I can't find any examples where this is done, could you show me an example I could reference?

Comment: yes one way is to enable the canvas then do a click so that we can get the circle around click, then to clieck the element actually we can disable the canvas

Comment: did you get a chance to try my answer? let me know if that helps @MitchellJanus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following. Let say you have a button

[image]

You can select it as

```
button = driver.find_element('xpath', '//button')
```

And then outline it

```
outline_style = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].style.outline", button) # Get initial outline style
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.outline = '#f00 solid 5px';", button) # Change outline style
button.click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.outline = arguments[1];", button, outline_style) # Set back initial outline style
```

[image]

**Yes, it's definitely not a circle**, but if you need to somehow make a focus on element you can use this approach

Comment: Perfect, is there a better way to remove the red outline after I take a screenshot than just doing driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.outline = '';", button)

Comment: @MitchellJanus no I think since we put the outline with JS, we need to remove it in the same way... But I guess you can re-define WebElement method `click` - add `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.outline = '';", self)` after click line

Comment: @MitchellJanus I think the best way would be to 1) Check initial style, 2) Set new outline, 3) Set back initial outline style after click. Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other solution using canvas. In the below code for this same page, we are trying to click on the bookmark button. Check the video the element that we are trying to cllick is colored blue and then clicked.

So basically what we have done here is created a canvas on the top of our page, got the location of the element, clicked on it to show the blue circle and then we click on the element after removing the canvas. Its important to remove the canvas before doing the actual click as canvas is overlayed on top of our page.

In the below code, all you need to change is the line `element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.js-bookmark-btn.s-btn.s-btn__unset.c-pointer.py4.js-gps-track')`  if you want to click on some other element on the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# REPLACE YOUR CHROME PATH HERE
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

def click_on_element(element):
    loc_dict = element.location
    circle_x, circle_y = loc_dict['x'] + element.size['width']//2, loc_dict['y'] + element.size['height']//2
    locX, locY = loc_dict['x'], loc_dict['y']

    createCircle = f'''
    document.body.appendChild(myCanvas);
        createCircle = function (event) {{
        var x = {circle_x};
        var y = {circle_y};
        ctx.fillStyle = "#2980b9";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        setTimeout(function () {{ ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height) }}, 2000);
    }}
    myCanvas.addEventListener("click", createCircle, true);
    '''
    driver.execute_script(createCircle)

    elementFromPoint = f'''el = document.elementFromPoint({locX}, {locY});
                         el.click();'''
    driver.execute_script(elementFromPoint)


    removeCanvasAndClick = f'''
    setTimeout(function () {{
        document.body.removeChild(myCanvas);
        myCanvas.removeEventListener('click', createCircle, true);
        el = document.elementFromPoint({locX}, {locY});
        el.click();
    }}, 1000);
    '''
    driver.execute_script(removeCanvasAndClick)

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73197807/selenium-python-is-it-possible-to-draw-a-circle-around-clicked-gui-elements'
s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

# Say, we want to click on bookmark
element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.js-bookmark-btn.s-btn.s-btn__unset.c-pointer.py4.js-gps-track')

#Create canvas
canvas = '''
myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
myCanvas.id = 'canvas';
myCanvas.style.position = 'absolute';
myCanvas.style.left = "0px";
myCanvas.style.top = "0px";
myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
'''
driver.execute_script(canvas)

# Circles the element that you want to click and then clicks on it
click_on_element(element_to_click)
```

Check out the youtube video below, for the run on this same page.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-Wz97xFPkI

[image]